# Remote OS authentication does not work with Oracle 21c PDB

Tags: oracle, authentication, pdb, oracle21c, cdb

I have a problem with Oracle 21c PDB connection. I have created an OS user which should be able to login to the Pluggable Database with...

```
sqlplus /
```

...command. However it does not work on the way how I have configured.

## **Details**

**OS:** Rocky Linux release 8.8 (Green Obsidian)

**Oracle version:** Oracle 21c

**CDB:** iqlink2c

**PDB:** iqlink2

Below you may find the steps...

1.) I have created the **orasync** OS (Linux - Rocky 8) user with the following parameters in the **.cshrc** file...

```
setenv ORACLE_BASE /opt/oracle
setenv ORACLE_HOME $ORACLE_BASE/product/21c/dbhome_1
setenv ORACLE_SID iqlink2
setenv ORACLE_TERM xsun5
setenv NLS_LANG AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8ISO8859P1
setenv PATH ${PATH}:${ORACLE_HOME}/bin
setenv EDITOR /bin/vi
```

2.) I logged in to the **Pluggable Database (iqlink2)** and I have created the orasync DB user with the following statement...

```
create user orasync
identified externally
default tablespace COMPANY
temporary tablespace TEMP
quota unlimited on COMPANY
quota unlimited on COMPANY_INDX
/
```

...and granted dba privileges...

```
GRANT dba TO orasync
/
```

3.) I logged into the **Container Database (iqlink2c)** and I checked the **os_authent_prefix** and **remote_os** parameters...

```
SQL> SHOW PARAMETERS os_authent_prefix;

NAME                     TYPE    VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
os_authent_prefix            string  ops$
SQL> SHOW PARAMETERS remote_os;

NAME                     TYPE    VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
remote_os_roles              boolean     FALSE
SQL>
```

***NOTE:** I know that the **remote_os_authent** parameter should be **TRUE**, but it's not available anymore with Oracle 21c at all. At this point I wonder if the remote OS login even possible with Oracle 21c PDB?!*

4.) I removed the **os_authent_prefix** value, then restarted the DB...

```
[oracle@company02 ~]$ sqlplus sys@iqlink2c as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sat Nov 11 00:52:45 2023
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password: 

Connected to:
Oracle Database 21c Enterprise Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 21.3.0.0.0

SQL> alter system set os_authent_prefix='' scope=SPFILE;

System altered.

SQL> shutdown immediate;
Database closed.
Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> startup; 
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 4294967152 bytes
Fixed Size          9695088 bytes
Variable Size        3388997632 bytes
Database Buffers      872415232 bytes
Redo Buffers           23859200 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
SQL> show parameter os_authent_prefix;              

NAME                     TYPE    VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
os_authent_prefix            string
```

5.) I logged in with the **orasync** user and tried to log in to the Pluggable Database...

```
[orasync@company02 ~]$ sqlplus /

SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sat Nov 11 01:04:49 2023
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
ORA-27101: shared memory realm does not exist
Linux-x86_64 Error: 2: No such file or directory
Additional information: 4775
Additional information: 1962365431
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

Enter user-name:
```

...and I have alsotried with...

```
[orasync@company02 ~]$ sqlplus /@iqlink2

SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sat Nov 11 00:47:53 2023
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

**ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied**

Enter user-name:
```

At this point I don't really understand why does not work, because I get answer for **tnsping**...

```
[orasync@company02 ~]$ tnsping iqlink2

TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on 11-NOV-2023 01:08:00

Copyright (c) 1997, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
/opt/oracle/product/21c/dbhome_1/network/admin/sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = iqlinkxg02)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = iqlink2)))
OK (0 msec)
[orasync@company02 ~]$
```

...and I can also log in with an other DB user from the same OS user...

```
[orasync@company02 ~]$ sqlplus sys1@iqlink2

SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sat Nov 11 01:09:18 2023
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password: 
Last Successful login time: Sat Nov 11 2023 01:03:42 +01:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 21c Enterprise Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 21.3.0.0.0

SQL>
```

---

The first thing what I tried to solve this was that to remove the ops$ value of the **os_authent_prefix** parameter, but in this case I got the `ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied` error.

An other thing what I tried was that I configured an Oracle 19c client on the server and modified the .cshrc file of the orasync user accordingly. The configuration was OK, because I could log in to the DB with an other DB user, but I was still getting the `ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied` error.

On the top of that I tried to add the `setenv TWO_TASK $ORACLE_SID` parameter to the .cshrc file, but it's just a formal change actually, did not help.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`remote_os_authentication` was removed with good reason. It was a MAJOR security vulerability. *Any* client - even a hacker - with a local user sharing the same name as a database user could connect to the database. This is an authentication architecture that should never, never, **never** be used.

That said, a PDB cannot be connected to directly in the way you are describing. Only a CDB can be connected to with IPC-type connections. For a PDB you *must* specify a TNS alias and connect through the network listener. You can then use an Oracle Wallet on the client to hold username/password credentials and achieve the same effect as an OS authenticated IPC connection.

See documentation here: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/security/twp-db-security-secure-ext-pwd-stor-133399.pdf

and here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/configuring-authentication.html#GUID-3EA07020-A9F3-4FF9-9518-E1AEA3BDDBBE

The basic steps are:

1. create a wallet
2. add username/password credentials to the wallet
3. configure sqlnet.ora to point to the wallet
4. connect using something like `sqlplus /@pdb_tns_alias`

Also note: Oracle server isn't supported on your Linux distro; for correct functionality you should use Oracle Linux.

Comment: Hey pmdba,

Many thanks for your input! I will give a try with Oracle Wallet (I have never configured it before) and I hope it will solve my problem and I will can connect with sqlplus /@iqlink2 string :)

Comment: Note that using a wallet doesn't negate the need for password authentication: your login account *must* have a password, but it will be stored in the wallet along with the username and provided automatically to the database during the login process. It gives the *appearance* of OS authentication without some of the inherent drawbacks.

Comment: Dear pmdba, it worked! It was fairly simple to configure the wallet. I was missing a description about the permission of the wallet files. I could only log in to the DB after I modified the permission of the wallet files to 644. But I figured this out fairly quickly so it does not hurt :) After all, I really appreciate your useful inputs! Cheers, Mike

Comment: Thank you! If you feel the answer was helpful, please mark it as correct so that others can find it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your new OS user (orasync) can use Oracle OS authentication, then you have to modify orasync's OS membership to be a member of Oracle dba group (usually dba, using `#usermod`).
When sitting at OS level, you can not directly connect to Pluggable database using OS authentication (because it just leave you at root database).

The workaround is to append `tnsnames.ora` file with Net Service Name of your PDB (if not exist).
Then using this syntax:

```
[orasync@company02 ~]$ sqlplus orasync/<password>@<Net_service_name_of_iqlink2>
```

Note: this walkaround does not require OS membership modification!
Good luck!

Comment: Hi Duong,

Many thanks for your input! My tnsnames.ora file has been configured correctly, as you can see in the description I can connect from the orasync OS user with an other DB user to the PDB. The point is, I have to connect to the DB without password authentication, so the connection string should be simply sqlplus / and that's it. As I can see from pmdba comment's above, I should use Oracle Wallet in this case.